# Image.FromFile will open a path, but not a string containing same path?

Tags: c#, string, image, picturebox, fromfile

```
// The following line works.
imagebox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/pic1.png");

// The following line does not work.
imagebox.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);

// the test Text Box displays "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/pic1.png", exactly like in the first line
test.Text = imgPath;
```

When i click the button that is supposed to change the picturebox's image, i get an error basically saying **illegal characters in path**, and **ArgumentException was unhandled**

sorry for not doing that the first time.

k so the actual filename is being entered into a text box. I'm then converting that text into a string, and adding it to the begging and end to create a full file path.

```
string path = "\"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/";
string ext1 = ".png\"";


ID = idBox.Text;
imgPath = path + ID + ext1;
try
{
    imagebox.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Student or Faculty ID.");
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we use tags for on SO.

Comment: Error message?  Exception?  Silent failure?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but if the text box literally displays:

> "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/pic1.png"

Then you have quotes in your path, which is bad. In your code you use the quotes to define a string, if you're grabbing input from a user you don't need the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Both lines should work just fine, so obviously, what your code is doing is not what you *think* it is doing.

I see you use text boxes to examine the values of your variables? Do yourself a favor and learn:

1. `Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` and
2. How to use the debugger.

(Most importantly the debugger.) You will then be able to figure out what is wrong with your code. Because from what you have shown us, it is impossible to find anything wrong with it.

--Oh yes, and please, next time you post something here telling us "it does not work", please tell us **exactly in what way it does not work**.  Does it silently do nothing? Does it throw an exception? Does it load an image other than the one you were expecting? Does it crash and burn? It is a tad essential.

Comment: When i click the button that is supposed to change the picturebox's image, i get an error basically saying illegal characters in path, and ArgumentException was unhandled..

Comment: @user1144513: How are you setting the imgpath variable? Are you sure it is not using backslashes instead of forward slashes (and they are not being escaped like this \\\)?

Comment: Thank you. Please put that in your question so that others will see it too.

Comment: Try using @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apps\pic1.png"

Comment: Mike W, imagebox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/pic1.png"); works fine, it only crashes and reports the error when I have "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/apps/pic1.png" in a string. if there is a way to add the @ verbatim literal in the string please explain

Answer (score 0):

Change the path,

```
string imgPath=@"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apps\pic1.png";
```

EDIT: Path contains invalid character.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apps\";
string ext1 = ".png";
ID = idBox.Text;
imgPath = path + ID + ext1;
if(System.IO.File.Exists(imgPath))
   imagebox.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
```

Comment: Yes, but we still do not know why he is receiving that error.

Comment: @user1144513 - Please show us **how imgPath var is assigned**.

Comment: k well that is going to take a bit more explanation. I'll put it in the original question

Comment: thank you a lot but Eric Rahm fixed it by simply taking out the \" i had at the beginning and end of the path. The quotation marks were causing it to fail. I did not realize they were just defining a string. can you explain why the if statement instead of the try-catch statement is better?

Answer (score 0):

Your slashes are the wrong way around. Try making it a Verbatim string, ie:

@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apps\pic1.png"